# Subtract dates and only show integer in SQL

Tags: sql, date, time, formatting, subtraction

I'm trying to find the days difference between two dates, and when I write: 'select date_trunc('day',timetable.time) - date_released as no_days', I get a result that shows something like: "0 years 0 mons 3 days 16 hours 38 mins 28.00 secs". I only want to see '3' or '3 days'. Is there a way to eliminate years, mons, hours, mins, secs? I"m running this query in Mode Analytics, if that changes anything...

Comment: Is this an oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, floor is your friend.

```
select sysdate - {ts '2017-08-01 15:30:00'} c
from dual
```

returns `216.921412037037037037037037037037037037`

while

```
select floor(sysdate - {ts '2017-08-01 15:30:00'}) c
from dual
```

returns `216`

Comment: What is "{ts '2017-08-01 15:30:00'}"? I've never seen such a query in Oracle. In fact, it raises an error (ORA-00911: invalid identifier) on my 11g XE.

Comment: It's something I did in ColdFusion, but using an Oracle database.

Comment: Aha, so it is ColdFusion syntax, actually. OK, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL for Sql Server the standard datediff functions is easiest.

Try this:
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/01/2009', GETDATE())

That return the number of days between 01/01/2009 and today.

If it is Oracle, the DateDiff syntax is about the same:

DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)

DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.

HTH,
Sean

Comment: The fact that he's using a minus operator suggests that he is not using sql server.

Comment: OK, so the Oracle example I gave is EXACTLY what he asked for "I'm trying to find the days difference between two dates"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, in Oracle difference of two DATE values results in number of days, so - just subtract them and remove everything behind the decimal point (which would be the TRUNC). For example:

```
SQL> select
  2    sysdate,
  3    sysdate - to_date('01.03.2018 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') diff,
  4    trunc(sysdate - to_date('01.03.2018 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) result
  5  from dual;

SYSDATE                   DIFF     RESULT
------------------- ---------- ----------
06.03.2018 21:20:35 5,01429398          5

SQL>
```